# Twig/Symfony not rendering form_widget

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a twig template (`home.twig`), and I'm using

```
{{ render(controller('WebsiteUserBundle:Registration:register',{ 'template': 'popup'} )) }}
```

inside that template to render another template (`login.twig`), which is used to login the user from a popup.

The problem is that the `form_widget` isn't rendered, but the `form_label` is.

This is part of my login template:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    {{ form_label(form.email, 'Email:')}}
    {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'span12'} }) }}
</div>
```

And by "it's not rendered", I mean that there isn't even an empty `div` or `input` next to the `label` element in the DOM.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Any errors in dev.log? Also, can you show us the form definition?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was because I had the follow sentence before the form_widget

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Check that the form_rest be after of all your form_widget.

Answer (score 0):

if you get only form_widget without extra params, like this :

```
{{ form_widget(form.email) }}
```

do you have more informations or any output ?